# Differences in Yin Naruto and Yang Naruto?

Tags: naruto

Initially, Naruto had Yang Kurama, said as the physical form or so. It gave him certain chakra and abilities.

Later in war he had Yin Kurama, the spiritual form, like genjutsu I believe. It must have given him some different abilities other than those given by the Sage of Six Paths. What are these?

And what were Naruto's post-Sasuke fight powers when he had both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yin is the power to create form out of nothingness. It is related to spiritual energy.

Yang breathes life into form. It relates to physical energy.

Source: http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Yin_Release

http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Yang_Release

Because Naruto had a Yang Nine Tails, it follows that he would gain access to the Nine Tails physical benefits and overflowing life energy. This manifested in super strength, rapid healing, and overflowing stamina.

If you look at how Nine Tails chakra was employed, you can see that Naruto had trouble giving it form. That's because he had massive power (Yang) but he wasn't given the power needed to shape it efficiently (Yin). When he did gain access to the Yin power, he found it much easier to manipulate changes in chakra nature and vary his types of Rasengan.

Comment: Did yin Naruto had less strenght, healing and stamina?

Comment: Yin Naruto had Six Paths blessing still on him to some degree. As a result, he would not appear weaker compared to Yang Naruto pre six Paths.